# Access column just created in same CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like this. Basically date and time.

```
DECLARE @sample table
(
    _date date,
    _time Time(0)
)

INSERT INTO @sample
VALUES
('2022-06-22', '09:00:00'),
('2022-06-22', '09:30:00'),
('2022-06-22', '10:00:00'),
('2022-06-22', '10:30:00'),
('2022-06-22', '11:00:00'),
('2022-06-23', '09:00:00'),
('2022-06-23', '09:30:00'),
('2022-06-23', '10:00:00');
```

And I added row number to it.

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY _date ORDER BY _time) AS rn     
    FROM @sample    
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
```

After that, the data look like this.

```
| _date      | _time    | rn |
|------------|----------|----|
| 2022-06-22 | 09:00:00 | 1  |
| 2022-06-22 | 09:30:00 | 2  |
| 2022-06-22 | 10:00:00 | 3  |
| 2022-06-22 | 10:30:00 | 4  |
| 2022-06-22 | 11:00:00 | 5  |
| 2022-06-23 | 09:00:00 | 1  |
| 2022-06-23 | 09:30:00 | 2  |
| 2022-06-23 | 10:00:00 | 3  |
```

Say now I want to loop though each row and modify the rn column, each rn is itself + rn from last row.

```
| _date      | _time    | rn |
|------------|----------|----|
| 2022-06-22 | 09:00:00 | 1  |
| 2022-06-22 | 09:30:00 | 3  |
| 2022-06-22 | 10:00:00 | 6  |
| 2022-06-22 | 10:30:00 | 10 |
| 2022-06-22 | 11:00:00 | 15 |
| 2022-06-23 | 09:00:00 | 16 |
| 2022-06-23 | 09:30:00 | 18 |
| 2022-06-23 | 10:00:00 | 21 |
```

How can I add row number and do that in same CTE scope?

I know I can probably get away with another CTE right after and use `LAG()` function to get previous row and do what ever modification I want with that `rn` column, but somehow I need to do this in one CTE and it is a little too complicated to explain.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: If you can't use another CTE, just use a nested query? `WITH  foo AS (SELECT bar FROM (SELECT x FROM y) AS z) SELECT * FROM foo`

Answer (score 5):

A possible option is an additional windowed `SUM()` (I assume, that the rows are ordered by the `_date` column):

```
; WITH cte AS (
   SELECT 
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY _date ORDER BY _time) AS rn
   FROM @sample
)
SELECT 
   _date, _time, 
   SUM(rn) OVER (ORDER BY _date, rn) AS rn
FROM cte
```

Comment: Probably more efficient to use `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` it's also more accurate if there are duplicate dates

Comment: While `SUM` is the right thing to do, it is not in the same `CTE`, as I understand that is what the OP is asking.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó To do it "within the same CTE (level)" just needs a minor change to select from a derived table instead of a CTE - though unclear why this requirement exists.

Comment: @MartinSmith Technically yes, I assumed (also in my answer) that that is also not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

As @Zhorov pointed out, you don't need `LAG`, as it is just a `SUM` - however as you mentioned that you really want to have the numbers from one `CTE`, the two could be combined like this:

```sql
WITH cte AS(  
    SELECT *,  
        SUM(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY _date ORDER BY _time)) OVER (ORDER BY _date, _time) AS rn  
    FROM @sample  
)  
SELECT *  
FROM cte
```

However, this can not be done, because `Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate.`.

I was thinking about how to eliminate the inner `ROW_NUMBER()` because it is an easy logic, and came up with this:

```sql
WITH cte AS(  
    SELECT *,  
        SUM((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @sample as inter WHERE inter._date = exter._date and inter._time <= exter._time)) OVER (ORDER BY _date, _time) AS rn  
    FROM @sample as exter  
)  
SELECT *  
FROM cte
```

But I don't know how much it hurts performance due to the correlated subquery - it really should be done in 2 separate set operations = not in the same `CTE`, or with a subquery in the `CTE`'s `FROM` clause.